# assistance with adding the date to the filename for batch files

Tags: batch-rename

How do I add the date to the file name in a batch file?

Here is what I have so far.

```
@ECHO OFF

move "k:\inventory\Inventory summary.csv" "K:\inventory\inventory summary &DD&-%MM%.CSV"
```

I just cant get it to input the month and day.